# Taking my e6410 dell from 32 to 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit

Am I going to see a major performance boost on Microsoft Office and Dev/DB apps if I switch up from 32-bit to 64-bit Windows on my Dell E6410 i5?

Comment: Unless you are loading up a a 20GB database, then no.  You might actually see **slower** performance.

Comment: If the apps are not 64bit, there is no reason to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it, especially if your total memory available is near 4GB. It's actually possible that you could experience a slow down from that upgrade.

If you've got near or more than 4GB, I think it'll start to become worth it.

Answer (score 3):

No. Productivity and development tools are the *least* likely to benefit from the 64-bit advantages since they are heavily dependent on user input.

Comment: I was told Word did better with more RAM, and I'm limited to 4gb with 32-bit Windows. Though I'm not super convinced an SSD wouldn't pep things up.

Comment: Word does better when you go from 256MB to 512MB. At 4GB you're throwing a pebble into the ocean. Besides, it's not limited to 4GB per se; there are artificial limits built into the various Windows SKUs.

Comment: There are no artificial limits in the 32 bits versions. The most commonly encountered limit is around 3.5 GB, as you cannot have 4GB of RAM and a videocard in only 4GB of address space.

Comment: @MSalters: Perhaps you're not familiar with [Microsoft's list of memory limits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).